# Turn on template paths using command line

Tags: magento2

Is there any command to turn off/on the template path hints?
Now that most of the things are controlled by command line, it would be nice to have command to turn on/off the hints :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you're using [magerun for Magento 2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2). The command to enable hints would be:

```
n98-magerun2.phar config:set dev/debug/template_hints_storefront 1
```

And just replace the '1' with '0' to disable. (Note: this is just for frontend. You'd have to update the dev/debug/template_hints_admin config setting for admin template hints.)